# Spacing between navigationBarItems

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationbar, spacing, navigationbaritems

How can I separate two buttons located in `.navigationBarItems` so they appear in different corners of the screen like here:

[image]

Here's the code I'm using:

```
.navigationBarItems(leading:
    HStack {
        EditButton()
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {
                someAction()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
        }
)
```

`Spacer()` doesn't help here and those two buttons still go together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different modifier, with leading and trailing parameters, like

```
.navigationBarItems(
     leading: EditButton(), 
     trailing: 
        Button(action: {
                someAction()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you add two buttons in leading then you separate them ?
you can use leading and trailing like this :

> ```
>         .navigationBarItems(leading:  EditButton(),  
>                             trailing: Button(action: {
>                                        someAction()
>                                      }) {
>                                        Image(systemName: "plus")
>                                      }     
>                              )
> ```